# How to register code with the deviceready event in a Cordova / Ionic project?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am taking over a Cordova/Ionic project. I've never worked with Cordova or Ionic before, so I am complete beginner in that area. However, I have worked with Node, on and off, for a few years, so I mostly know about that.

A simple starting task, I need to add Appsee:

https://www.appsee.com/docs/ios/ionic

This part was easy:

```
In case you're using TypeScript (default in ionic 2 and ionic 3) place the following line under the imports:

declare var Appsee:any;
```

Which I put in this file:

./src/app/app.component.ts

But this part is less obvious:

```
Call the following method when your app starts, preferably when the deviceready event fires:

Appsee.start("YOUR API KEY");
```

So I ran grep to find out where deviceready is:

```
grep -iR "deviceready" *   | grep -v node_modules

www/build/vendor.js:     * resolve when Cordova triggers the `deviceready` event.
www/build/vendor.js:            // prepare a custom "ready" for cordova "deviceready"
www/build/vendor.js:                    doc.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
www/build/vendor.js:                        // 3) cordova deviceready event triggered
www/build/vendor.js:    var deviceReady = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
www/build/vendor.js:            document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
www/build/vendor.js:    var deviceReadyDone = deviceReady.catch(function () {
www/build/vendor.js:        return deviceReadyDone.then(function () {
www/build/vendor.js:    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
www/build/vendor.js:        console.log("Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after " + (Date.now() - before) + " ms");
www/build/vendor.js:            console.warn("Ionic Native: deviceready did not fire within " + DEVICE_READY_TIMEOUT + "ms. This can happen when plugins are in an inconsistent state. Try removing plugins from plugins/ and reinstalling them.");
```

So I only see "deviceready" inside the `build` folder. I think I'm supposed to avoid editing anything inside of `build`? Isn't that full of stuff that's generated by Ionic/Cordova?

Where do I register something with deviceready?

If I run:

```
ionic info
```

I get:

```
[WARN] Detected locally installed Ionic CLI, but it's too old--using global CLI.

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4
    Cordova Platforms  : none
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
    Node       : v6.5.0
    npm        : 3.10.3 
    OS         : OS X El Capitan
    Xcode      : Xcode 7.3.1 Build version 7D1014 

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

I'm happy to follow directions from elsewhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use **Platform** to get device ready event in IONIC, In your app.component.ts

> 1. import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
> 2. Add platform.ready() method inside the constructor as shown below

```
constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      Appsee.start("YOUR API KEY");
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
```

}

it will be triggered when device/platform is ready.
[Here is the documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your app.module and nothing will occur before the platofrm is ready. Like that you dont have to worry what will be the entry point of your angular app.

```
providers: [
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: (platform: Platform) => {
    return () => platform.ready()
  },
  deps: [Platform],
  multi: true
}]
```